# c++ please i cant figure out what is wrong here

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
bool stringCompare(char*A, char*B)
{
    while(*A!=" && *B!=")
    {
        if (*A != *B)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        A++;
        B++;
```

I don't know what I did wrong but I keep getting an error in the while loop. I tried using the strncmp instead but I get the same error. I would really appreciate it if I could get help on it.

Comment: What error? Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Please post a complete program which demonstrates your problem along with an explanation of what the program should do and what the program is doing which is incorrect.

Comment: You're missing two closing braces `}`

Comment: `*A!=" && *B!="` should be `*A && *B`

Comment: That's a single double-quote character instead of a double single-quote character in both cases. What you have here is not valid syntax, as evidenced by the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Hey!! You can't edit your question and change it completely to ask another question.    This makes the two answers completely irrelevant.  This is not the way to proceed;  if you want another question, create a new one please.  I've rolledback the edit to correct the situation

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

The double quote `"` is not a replacement for two single quotes. This leads the compiler to think you want to compare the char `*A` with the string `" && *B!="` thus a weird error message.

And two single quotes `''` do not represent a valid character either.  There is no empty char literal: either there is a char (which could be null) or there is no char.

#### The solution to get it compiled

So change your loop condition to

```
while(*A!='\0' && *B!='\0')
```

or even

```
while(*A!=0 && *B!=0)
```

which is equivalent to

```
while(*A && *B)
```

The full code is then:

```
bool stringCompare(char*A, char*B)
{
    while(*A && *B)
    {
        if (*A != *B)
        {
            return false;
        }
        A++;
        B++;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

#### But is it correct ?

Depends on your expectations.  If you have one string longer than the other,  the programme will stop assuming it the comparison is over.  But I only assumed the end of the function, so maybe you did the have the following correct return statement at the end:

```
return *A==*B;  // returns true only if both are equal meaning both 0
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/IeaDEQ)

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
*A!=" && *B!="
```

is attempting to compare the character pointed to by `A` with the *string literal* `" && *B!="`. That's not going to do what you expect.

If your intent is to simply look until you've reached the end of both strings (which is what you need for a string compare<sup>(1)</sup>), the `while` loop should be:

```
while(*A != '\0' || *B != '\0')
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This is assuming the idea is to treat the strings for equality, which is probably what you want. They will be treated as equal as equal if ***they are the same length*** and all characters are identical. Using `&&` will only check the characters up to the length of the shortest string, so `"pax"` and `"paxdiablo"` would be considered equal.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but with `(*A != '\0' || *B != '\0')`, wouldn't it loop until both chars are `\0` in the same time ?  So if comparing "ABC" with "ABCD", it might iterate out of the bounds of the char arrays and therfore lead to UB ?

Comment: @Christophe: Yes, the *loop* would do that but, fortunately, if they are different lengths, the code *within* the loop will exit when either one is finished (since the `\0` in the short string and non-`\0` character in the long string will be different).